# How to add numbers in an editText

Tags: java

I am new to java dev. I want to add numbers in an editText.
i.e if user types in 15 in editText, it should add the numbers 1 + 5 giving the result 6.
Is there a function for it in java. In C# it is ToCharArray() but I don't know what it's called in java.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
    String str = "15";
    char[] cArray = str.toCharArray();

    int sum = 0;
    for (char c : cArray)
        sum += Character.digit(c, 10);
```

Comment: I am using the above code, but the app seems to crash.Also I am getting error (cannot parse int here)  when I try to use sum += Integer.parseInt(c)
Any help will be great.

Comment: Also how can i put the result in a textview. I am using textv.setText(sum) but it doesn't seems to be working.

Comment: @artist try my edit for the error. As far as the textView, textv.setText(sum.toString()) should work.

Comment: still says that application has stopped unexpectedly.

Comment: It works now. I want to know what does 10 stands for in the above code     sum += Character.digit(c, 10);
Thanks

Comment: Should I create another method to check for decimal in editText since I do not want user to enter decimal in editText. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When translating between C# and Java, you can get *very* far by doing nothing more than changing the capitalization. The equivalent method in Java's String class is "toCharArray()", starting with a lower-case "t".